# How to check which pytorch version fits torchvision

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to clone and run this repository:
https://github.com/switchablenorms/CelebAMask-HQ

The demo runs with PyTorch 0.4.1, and I am trying to find the corresponding version, how can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding torchvision version for `0.4.1` is `0.2.1`.

The easiest way is to look it up in the [previous versions section](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/). Only if you couldn't find it, you can have a look at the torchvision release data and pytorch's version. There you can find which version, got release with which version!

Answer (score 1):

One way to find the torch-to-torchvision correspondence is by looking at

- the tables on https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/
- or (even better) https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/PyTorch-Versions

Based on that, the current version at the time of this writing is `0.2.2`.